# How to get the last 6th(from current date)week data in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to date object of last 6th week date from the current date.

```
var cuurrentDate = new Date();
```

Ex. Current date:

> Jul 06 2016 hh:mm:ss GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)

I want to display the date of last 6th week:

Output:

> May 25 2016 hh:mm:ss GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.setDate()` and subtract *number of days* from *current date*

```js
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var numOfWeeks = 6;
date.setDate(d - (numOfWeeks * 7));
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by last 6th week, you mean exactly 6 * 7 days ago (42).

You can modify the date instance using the `setDate` method, passing it the current instance's `getDate` subtracted by 42 days. For example:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 42);
```